# Random easing Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to know a way to perform custom or randon easing with jQuery animate() function.

I know that there's a plugin with lots of easings, but I want to know if there's a way of adding custom easings

So instead of linear:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111 (velocity)
```

or swing:

```
00011111222222444422222211111000 (velocity)
```

I get something like:

```
0011128833747733322885666111221100 (velocity)
```

The numbers above represent the velocity. I want to make it random to make it look a little bit more realistic and not so scheduled.

Comment: You can create your own easings, but as far as I know there are no random easings available.

Comment: what you want to animate? perhaps its a better solution doing it with css3 or a svg animation?

Comment: Some particles coming from the side of the screen

Comment: Tried http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ ? , http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/ ?

Comment: they are mostly symmetrical or structured easings and don't give the illusion of naturalism

Comment: Can describe "naturalism" ? asymmetrical animations ? Do "particles" appear to move from one side of viewport (screen) to other side of viewport ? Can include `html` , `css` , `js` ? , create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

define custom function.

```js
jQuery.easing.custom = function( p ){
    var pow2,
  bounce = 4;
    while ( p < ( ( pow2 = Math.pow( 2, --bounce ) ) - 1 ) / 11 ) {}
  return 1 / Math.pow( 4, 3 - bounce ) - 7.5625 * Math.pow( ( pow2 * 3 - 2 ) / 22 - p, 2 );
};
console.log(jQuery.easing.custom(5756836523456436));
$("button").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.6
}, 2000, "custom", function(){
    $( this ).after( "<div>Animation complete.</div>" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
    animate
</button>
```